# Extract GPA from Resume through Python Using PyMyPDF

Tags: python, pdf, pymupdf

**We made a program for simple Resume that extract the whole Resume Info in string line by line. Now I want to extract the GPA from that string. I tried a lot but could not get any idea regard this. So if anyone could configure this will be very helpful for me.**

```
import fitz
import os

pdfFiles = []
for filename in os.listdir('resume/'):
    if filename.endswith('.pdf'):
        print(filename)
        os.chdir('C:/Users/M. Abrar Hussain/Desktop/cv/resume')
        pdfFileObj = open(filename, 'rb')
        with fitz.open(pdfFileObj) as doc:
            text = ""
            for page in doc:
                text += page.getText()
            print(text)
            p = doc.loadPage(0)
            p_text = p.getText()
            p_lines = p_text.splitlines()
            print(p_lines)
            search_keywords = ['Laravel', 'Java', 'Python']
            # Comparing data with keywords
            lst = []
            for sentence in p_lines:
                for word in search_keywords:
                    if word in sentence:
                        lst.append(word)
            print(lst)

            score = 0
            w1 = []

            for w1 in lst:
                if w1 == 'Laravel':
                    score = score + 2
                if w1 == 'Python':
                    score = score + 2
                if w1 == 'Java':
                    score = score + 1

            print("The candidate has Score = %i" % score)
            print('\n')
        pdfFileObj.close()
```

**The output of this Code is**

```
cv1.pdf
Name: M. Abrar Hussain 
GPA: 3.5 
Skills: Python, Laravel 
Experience: 3 yr 

['Name: M. Abrar Hussain ', 'GPA: 3.5 ', 'Skills: Python, Laravel ', 'Experience: 3 yr ']
['Laravel', 'Python']
The candidate has Score = 4


cv2.pdf
Name: Danish Ejaz 
GPA: 3.7 
Skills: Python, Java 
Experience: 2.5 yr 

['Name: Danish Ejaz ', 'GPA: 3.7 ', 'Skills: Python, Java ', 'Experience: 2.5 yr ']
['Java', 'Python']
The candidate has Score = 3


cv3.pdf
Name: Abdullah 
GPA: 3.2 
Skills: Laravel, Java 
Experience: 2 yr 

['Name: Abdullah ', 'GPA: 3.2 ', 'Skills: Laravel, Java ', 'Experience: 2 yr ']
['Laravel', 'Java']
The candidate has Score = 3



Process finished with exit code 0
```

**In this output we able to compare the Skills with the KeyWord and give them Score. Now our main focus is to extract the GPA value form the string and give score after comparison as we did earlier to the Skills**

Comment: How exactly do you want to score it? Can you access the GPA from the list? Can you provide a reproducible code?

Comment: No i can't access the GPA from the list that's the main issue. If somehow i access the GPA then scoring them is not a difficult task. All i want is when i calling "GPA: " will give me the very next part that is the value of the GPA.

Comment: I applied the same method new_gpa= "GPA: #.##" but it gives me the output "':', ' ', 'G', 'P', 'A', ':', ' ', '.', 'P', ':', ' ', ':', ' ', '.']" which is not my required scenario.